# Which of the following subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Which of the following subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$?
>
> A. The $3 \times 3$ matrices with determinant 0
> B. The $3 \times 3$ matrices whose entries are all integers
> C. The invertible $3 \times 3$ matrices
> D. The $3 \times 3$ matrices with all zeros in the first row
> E. The diagonal $3 \times 3$ matrices
> F. The symmetric $3 \times 3$ matrices

I answered B, D, E and F, but it appears to be incorrect. How so?

Answer (score 2):

(B) is false, since there are $\;3\times3\;$ integer matrices which multiplied by $\;\frac12\;$ aren't integer anymore (example?)

$$$$